# nn.Linear(feature_size, 1)*n vs nn.Linear(feature_size, n) in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch

I write two types of liner-classifier in PyTorch:

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
fc = []  
for i in range(n):  
  fc.append(nn.Linear(feature_size, 1))
```

The other:

```
torch.manual_seed(0)
fc = nn.Linear(feature_size, n)
```

And different results were obtained using these two types of fc in a 
multi-label classification model.

Actually, those fc initialized differently and leads to different results. Which one is correct and what should I do if I want the similar results using two types of fc.

---

Additional Information:

I find out the reason lead to bad result:
The first type FC not updates in training!
But I don't know why there is no updating, my code as follow:

```
x = self.features(input)
res = []
for i in range(self.num_classes):
    res.append(self.fc[i](x.cpu()))
res = torch.cat(res, 1)
return res.cuda()
```

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you initialize the two types to the **exact** same values? do they still learn different classifications?
What loss function are you using on top of these classifiers? Is it the same loss function?

In terms of computations, both types are performing the same: they multiply the input feature vector with `n` weight vectors. Thus, if the weight vectors have the same values, both types should output the same classifications.
I suppose in terms of runtime and efficiency it is better to use one `n` dimensional classifier as oppose to `n` 1D: this way, I believe, allows for more hardware acceleration options.

Comment: I cannot write code here, please move to my answer above. thank u.

Comment: does your object inherit from `nn.Module`?